How to replace a line in a table and maintain the same table appearance in beamer?
I'd like to substitute a line by another in a tabular in beamer, however the substituted line is significantly smaller in size and the tabular is enlarged very strongly: I'd like to keep a constant aspect of the tabular in the process, but I really don't see how... Would anyone have a solution ?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
   \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
   \usepackage{makecell}
   \usepackage{nicefrac}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Exemple de NH$_3$}
    NH$_3$: groupe $C_{3v}$
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{    \begin{tabular}{c|cccccc|c}
        $C_{3v}$  &$E$&$C_3$&$C_3^2$&$\sigma_v(1)$&$\sigma_v(2)$&$\sigma_v(3)$&\\\hline
        $\Gamma_1$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$1$          &$1$          &$1$          &$z$\\
        $\Gamma_2$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$-1$          &$-1$          &$-1$          &$z$\\
        \only<1>{$\Gamma_3$&\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$&\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$  &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix} $    &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$          &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\makecell{$z$\\ $z$} }
        \only<2->{ $\Gamma_2$&$2$&$-1$  &$-1$    &$0$          &$0$          &$0$          &\makecell{$z$\\ $z$}}
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Thanks a lot,
Marc
Edit:
I made some progress - rather ugly but improves on things :
\documentclass{beamer}
   \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
   \usepackage{makecell}
   \usepackage{nicefrac}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vecx}{\pmb{T}_x}
\newcommand{\vecy}{\pmb{T}_y}
\newcommand{\vecz}{\pmb{T}_z}
\newcommand{\rotx}{\pmb{R}_x}
\newcommand{\roty}{\pmb{R}_y}
\newcommand{\rotz}{\pmb{R}_z}
   

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Exemple de NH$_3$}
    NH$_3$: groupe $C_{3v}$
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5em}|
            >{\centering}p{0.06\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.07\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.17\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}|
            >{\centering}p{0.1\textwidth}
        }
        $C_{3v}$  &$E$&$C_3$&$C_3^2$&$\sigma_v(1)$&$\sigma_v(2)$&$\sigma_v(3)$&\\\hline
        $\Gamma_1$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$1$          &$1$          &$1$          &$\vecz$\\
        $\Gamma_2$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$-1$          &$-1$          &$-1$          &$\rotz$\\
        \only<2>{$\Gamma_3$&\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$&\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$  &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix} $    &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$          &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\makecell{$(\vecx,\vecy)$\\ $(\rotx,\roty)$} }
        \only<3->{ $\Gamma_2$&$2$&$-1$  &$-1$    &$0$          &$0$          &$0$          &\makecell{$(\vecx,\vecy)$\\ $(\rotx,\roty)$}}
    \end{tabular}
}



\end{frame}
\end{document}

Edit 2-4:
Following @DavidCarlisle and @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggestions I think I have improved my mess, however I have too much space between the first line and the \hline for some reason (fixed by [-4mm]) but the last line still moves a little bit when transitioning, which is quite annoying...
\documentclass{beamer}
   \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
   \usepackage{makecell}
   \usepackage{nicefrac}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vecx}{\pmb{T}_x}
\newcommand{\vecy}{\pmb{T}_y}
\newcommand{\vecz}{\pmb{T}_z}
\newcommand{\rotx}{\pmb{R}_x}
\newcommand{\roty}{\pmb{R}_y}
\newcommand{\rotz}{\pmb{R}_z}
   

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Exemple de NH$_3$}
    NH$_3$: groupe $C_{3v}$
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5em}|
            >{\centering}p{0.04\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.13\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.12\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.06\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.14\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.13\textwidth}|
            >{\centering}p{0.08\textwidth}
        }
        $C_{3v}$  &$E$&$C_3$&$C_3^2$&$\sigma_v(1)$&$\sigma_v(2)$&$\sigma_v(3)$&\\[-4mm]\hline
        $\Gamma_1$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$1$          &$1$          &$1$          &\footnotesize$\vecz$\\
        $\Gamma_2$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$-1$          &$-1$          &$-1$          &\footnotesize$\rotz$\\
        \only<1>{$\Gamma_3$&\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$&\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$  &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix} $    &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$          &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\footnotesize\makecell[tl]{$(\vecx,\vecy)$\\ $(\rotx,\roty)$} }
        \only<2->{ $\Gamma_3$&$2$&$-1$  &$-1$    &$0$          &$0$          &$0$          &\footnotesize\makecell[tl]{$(\vecx,\vecy)$\\ $(\rotx,\roty)$}}
    \end{tabular}

\end{frame}



\end{document}


always avoid using \resizebox on tables, especually here where you are rescaling the table differently on each overlay

Thanks for the suggestion but then how do I fit the table on my page ? I really need to do it...

@user22744 Choose a suitable font size or change the layout of the table to make it fit the available space.

If you are sure that the replacement text is shorter, you could use this quick hack:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={|c|c|c|}
    }
        test &
        \makebox[0pt][l]{\visible<2>{short text}}\visible<1>{$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$}
        &
        test\\
    \end{tblr}

\end{frame}
\end{document}



I love your hack !! Is it possible to also center the smaller text in the cell ?

@user22744 If you know the width of the column, you could place the shorter text in yet another box of this width to centre it.

OK, that's great !! Thank you very much. I like your solution - seems quite general to me.

Following @DavidCarlisle and @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggestions, a solution I find satisfying is provided below...even if the last line still moves a little bit when transitioning...
\documentclass{beamer}
   \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
   \usepackage{makecell}
   \usepackage{nicefrac}
   \usepackage{mathenv,amsmath}
\newcommand{\vecx}{\pmb{T}_x}
\newcommand{\vecy}{\pmb{T}_y}
\newcommand{\vecz}{\pmb{T}_z}
\newcommand{\rotx}{\pmb{R}_x}
\newcommand{\roty}{\pmb{R}_y}
\newcommand{\rotz}{\pmb{R}_z}
   

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Exemple de NH$_3$}
    NH$_3$: groupe $C_{3v}$
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5em}|
            >{\centering}p{0.04\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.13\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.12\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.06\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.14\textwidth}
            >{\centering}p{0.13\textwidth}|
            >{\centering}p{0.08\textwidth}
        }
        $C_{3v}$  &$E$&$C_3$&$C_3^2$&$\sigma_v(1)$&$\sigma_v(2)$&$\sigma_v(3)$&\\[-4mm]\hline
        $\Gamma_1$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$1$          &$1$          &$1$          &\footnotesize$\vecz$\\
        $\Gamma_2$&$1$&$1$  &$1$    &$-1$          &$-1$          &$-1$          &\footnotesize$\rotz$\\
        \only<1>{$\Gamma_3$&\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$&\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$  &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix} $    &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$          &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\tiny$\begin{pmatrix}\nicefrac{-1}{2}&\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\nicefrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\nicefrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$          &\footnotesize\makecell[tl]{$(\vecx,\vecy)$\\ $(\rotx,\roty)$} }
        \only<2->{ $\Gamma_3$&$2$&$-1$  &$-1$    &$0$          &$0$          &$0$          &\footnotesize\makecell[tl]{$(\vecx,\vecy)$\\ $(\rotx,\roty)$}}
    \end{tabular}

\end{frame}



\end{document}


Your code fails to compile on my mac.

What is the error ?

! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

Ah, I have it too on the MWE ! I did not recompile it as the solution works in my actual presentation, sorry... I'm going to try and correct it.

OK, the mathenv package was missing - I adjusted the solution accordingly... it works for me now.
